# Incorrect Invocation

Tags: javascript, html

> You have an incorrect invocation of a method because you are invoking it on the wrong object.

My mentor is telling me that I'm 'invoking a method' incorrectly. I have searched the web for this, I've looked on w3schools tutorials website and their call or invoke tutorials are not relevant to what issues I'm having.

The goal of this code is to target, edit, and add a new HTML element using JS.

**Javascript**

```
    function start(){
  let targetTag = document.querySelector('#list');
  let newItem = targetTag.createElement('li');
  newItem.innerText = ("Mens T-shirt");
  targetTag.prepend(newItem);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li>Biker Jacket</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Add Field" onClick="start();"/>
```

Comment: What method did your mentor tell you was invoked incorrectly?

Comment: None so far, thats just what they said is that I've invoked incorrectly. I'm invoking on the wrong object. I've rewritten the code and it still doesn't work. So it was not a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`targetTag.createElement` is wrong (it simply doesn't exist)—you should use `document.createElement`:

```
let newItem = document.createElement('li');
```

```js
function start() {
  // Select the list element (using querySelector
  // you select it by its id: #list)
  let targetTag = document.querySelector('#list');
  
  // Create in memory a new <li> element
  let newItem = document.createElement('li');
  
  // Set its content (text) to be "Mens T-shirt")
  newItem.innerText = ("Mens T-shirt");
  
  // Prepend it in the list (at this point you are 
  // adding it in the DOM)
  targetTag.prepend(newItem);
}


// Let's call the function
start()
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li>Biker Jacket</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The user has defined targetTag as the result of a selector.

Comment: @mrunion Exactly—but `targetTag.createElement` simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying. Yes, you are correct. My apologies.

Comment: So would you be able to explain how it knows where to create the new field?

Comment: appendChild here maybe better than prepend?

Comment: @LiveBacteria I added inline comments

Comment: @Pengcheng It really depends on the case—I assumed it should be prepended. Of course, if it should be added at the end, `appendChild` should be used.

Comment: They specifically asked me to use prepend, but now I know what appendChild is. Also thanks guys I can't believe I didn't notice how wrong that was..